# Unable to change metadata of m4v video file

Tags: windows, video, metadata

I want to change title of a m4v video. I have tried `Media Information` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) of VLC to change it, but its not working. I have also tried MetaX, but again no luck. I used both applications with Administrator privilege, too.

Where's the problem? How to change title of that m4v video file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like [AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) is what you want.

Examples:

```
AtomicParsley /path/to.mp4 -T 1
AtomicParsley /path/to.mp4 -t +
AtomicParsley /path/to.mp4 --artist "Me" --artwork /path/to/art.jpg
Atomicparsley /path/to.mp4 --albumArtist "You" --podcastFlag true
Atomicparsley /path/to.mp4 --stik "TV Show" --advisory explicit
```

To overwrite, use the `--overWrite` switch.

Comment: It has made the changes to a temp file (not the original file), but it works like a charm. Thanks..

Comment: There's an undocumented `--overWrite` switch, @SachinShekhar

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread--but I just discovered a possible answer. VLC fails to change metadata when the file is named `.m4v`, yet succeeds when it's `.mp4` --at least for me. Try renaming your files.

Comment: Have you even read the question?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I don't understand which "title" you want to change. I assumed it was the metadata. It only worked for me when I changed the file name from a .m4v to a .mp4.

Comment: Changing the extension worked? Surprising.. I'd test if I had that file at this time.

Comment: I can confirm that changing `Media Information` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) for a `.m4v` file failed. (It writes `[0x7fda609e4a48] taglib meta writer error: File XXXXXXX.m4v can't be opened for tag writing`. Renaming the file to XXXXXXX.mp4 temorarily while running VLC allowed me to change the media information successfully. So, @SS, have you even tried the suggested solution? :-)